# table data rearrange in R

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I am new to learning R. I have data set like this which is needed to be arranged to perform one way ANOVA.

```
Group    Salary

B         1000

A         2000

B         3000

A         4000
```

this needed to rearrange in to

```
Group A   Group B

2000      1000

4000      3000
```

thx

Comment: If you are looking for ANOVA, does this provide the answer you are looking for `summary(aov(Salary ~ Group, data=df))`?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `unstack` from `base R`

```
unstack(df, Salary~Group)
#   A    B
#1 2000 1000
#2 4000 3000
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Group = c("B", "A", "B", "A"), Salary = c(1000L, 
2000L, 3000L, 4000L)), .Names = c("Group", "Salary"),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```